# Can I assign RDLC object data source, my own data table?

Tags: asp.net, datatable, reporting, datasource, rdlc

I have an rdlc file that has a datasource. But I want to assign a data table to it at runtime. Can I do this in CS file?

I want to generate a datatable at runtime and want to use it in rdlc file's object datasource. Please suggest solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
var rptSource = new ReportDataSource("TableName", objDataTable);
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rptSource);
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```